# Creating a link in Umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I have created a document type using the 'Related Links' Type, with a name of 'Link 1' and an alias of 'Link1'.

I am using Razor to try and render out the link using the following line of code in my HTML.

```
   @using RJP.MultiUrlPicker.Models;

@{
  var multiUrlPicker = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1");
  if (multiUrlPicker.Any())
  {
    <ul>
      @foreach (var item in multiUrlPicker)
      {
        <li><a href="@item.Url" target="@item.Target">@item.Name</a></li>
      }
    </ul>
  }
}
```

The html doesnt render out in the source code.

Can anyone advise one where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Problem is that you are closing the opened quote mark when you do ("Link1").... you need to escape it or use single quotes around the href

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
var links = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("Link1");
var singleLink = JArray.Parse(links).FirstOrDefault();
if (singleLink != null){
    var linkUrl = singleLink.Value<bool>("isInternal") ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(singleLink.Value<int>("internal")) : singleLink.Value<string>("link");
    var linkTarget = (singleLink.Value<bool>("newWindow")) ? " target=\"_blank\"" : string.Empty;
    <a @Html.Raw(linkTarget) href="@linkUrl">@(singleLink.Value<string>("caption"))</a>
  }

}
```

That solution should work, but I recommend using [Multi Url Picker](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/multi-url-picker) since it's a lot easier to use and call from when using links.

Multi Url Picker way (single link)

```
var link = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("linkAlias").SingleOrDefault();
if (link != null){
<a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a>
}
```

As a collection:

```
@foreach ( var link in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("linkAlias")){
<a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have now installed the Multi URL Picker package and created a new Data Type, and have created a new Item in my document type called 'FooterOne'

I have added this code to my template to render out the links, but it doesnt seem to display any of the links?

    @{
  var multiUrlPickerDyn = CurrentPage.multiUrlPicker;
  if (multiUrlPickerDyn.Any())
      {
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          @foreach (var item in multiUrlPickerDyn)
          {
            <li><a href="@item.Url" target="@item.Target">@item.Name</a></li>
          }
        </ul>
      }
    }

Comment: I've added an example above. Remember to publish the page again if you amend the data type.

Comment: I think I'm getting lost when trying to define list of links I'm trying to display, as I'm trying to create separate menus in my footer.

Comment: I'm trying do do something like this.





@{
  var FooterOne = CurrentPage.multiUrlPicker;
  if (FooterOne.Any())
  {
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      @foreach (var item in FooterOne)
      {
        <li><a href="@item.Url" target="@item.Target">@item.Name</a></li>
      }
    </ul>
  }
}

Comment: What have you called the property in the doc type? I recommend calling the property footerLinks1 then you can call the links by using  var footerOne = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("footerLinks1");
 footerOne can then be looped over to extract the links.

Comment: The Doc type is called 'Home' with a generic property called 'footerlinks1' - I'm going to try again,

Comment: I'm now here...

My Alias for my Multi URL Picker is FooterLinks1 and this is the code I have applied.


    @foreach (var footerOne = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1"))

    {
    <a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a>
    }

Comment: If you're putting this on the master page, you'll have to reference the home node when getting the links since Model.Content will change for each node. Try 
var footerOne =  Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Home").GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1");

Make sure your aliases are correct. Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Ive now done this, the error message says 'in' is expected.


@foreach ( var footerOne = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Home").GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1")) 

{ <a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a> 


}

Comment: I'm putting it in a Partial View then importing the view into my master template, does that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry yeh it should have been : var footerOne = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue <MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1"); then foreach over that. Sorry I'm typing these on my phone! I'd you're doing it in a partial just make sure the partial inherits umbracotemplatepage

Comment: Still no joy with it, I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1515: 'in' expected

Source Error:


Line 15: 
Line 16:  
Line 17:  @foreach ( var footerOne = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue <MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1")){
Line 18: <a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a>
Line 19: }

Comment: @foreach ( var link in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("FooterLinks1")){
<a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a>
}

Comment: I now get this message.

The type or namespace name 'MultiUrls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add this at top:
@using RJP.MultiUrlPicker

Comment: Ive updated my code at the top of the page showing you where I am with it now, The html renders out in the source code, but it doesnt add the link to the page or the anchor tag.

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt throw an error but it also doesnt generate any links?

Comment: Ive figured it out - It doesnt render the links on the top page but it does render the links out on the Home page  if that makes any sense?